# Wordpress custom post type image in RSS

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development

i have a theme (classipress) that uses a custom post type 
the classified page doesn't use the wordpress featured image function
it uses its own image function 
I was able to include the custom post types in RSS but i could not include the image of the classified item in the RSS feed

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never I guess.

You have several options, first and easiest, you can install a plugin that searches for images in posts and the attach them as featured if no featured is found. [This plugin can help you](https://wordpress.org/plugins/set-all-first-images-as-featured/), but there are plenty more.

If you prefer not to rely in plugins, you can add a snippet in your `functions.php` file that searches for the first image in the post attachments and then features it. [You have a tutorial here](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-automatically-set-post-featured-image) on how to accomplish this.

Lastly, you need to include the featured image in your RSS feed:

```
// display featured post thumbnails in WordPress feeds
function wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds( $content ) {
global $post;
if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . '</p>' .     $content;
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds' );
```

Hope this helps.